# Increase color saturation with sass mixin

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I'm trying to write looped mixin that iteratively increases the saturation of a background-color.  Here's the latest mixin code:

```
@mixin generateBackgroundSteps($cell-count, $color) {
    @for $i from 0 through $cell-count - 1 {
        $percent: (5 * $i) + "%";
        $new-color: saturate($color, $percent);

        &[setting-id="#{$i}"] {
            background-color: $new-color;                
        }
    }
}
```

No matter how I've altered this, the produced css just keeps looking like this:

```
.rubric-design .rubric .create-new-criteria .create-criteria-initial-
settings .create-criteria-setting[setting-id="2"] {
      background-color: saturate(#90afc8);
}
```

Maybe it's the way I'm forming $percent.  It must be something obvious!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `percentage` function.

[percentage](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#percentage-instance_method) function in SCSS

```
$percent: percentage((5 * $i) / (5 * $cell-count));

@mixin generateBackgroundSteps($cell-count, $color) {
@for $i from 0 through $cell-count - 1 {
    $percent: percentage((5 * $i) / (5 *$cell-count));
    $new-color: saturate($color, $percent);

    &[setting-id="#{$i}"] {
        background-color: $new-color;                
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: That totally worked.  Thank you!  I modified it slightly to `$percent: percentage((10 * $i) / 100);`

Comment: @webhound great!